# How to write to list if columns and rows are dynamic?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I read some data dynamically from ms sql database. Im reading list of department(row as column heading) as columns and their corresponding designations as rows. I use the below code to bind that to list of class file

```
    String @querystring="....";
    IEnumerable<EmpDepartment> empdepartment = DB.ExecuteQuery<EmpDepartment>(@querystring).ToList();

        foreach (EmpDepartment empvar in empdepartment)
        {
            string Designame = empvar.Designation[0].DesignationName.ToString(); ---> Here it gives null             
        }
```

// My class looks this,

```
public class Designationlist
{       
    public int DesignationId{ get; set; }
    public int DesignationName{ get; set; }
}

public class EmpDepartment
{
    public string DepartmentName{ get; set; }
    public IList<Designationlist> Designation{ get; set; }
}
```

How to write to list if the columns and their corresponding rows are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
It should be of Designation,since designation of type Designationlist under EmpDepartment

foreach (EmpDepartment empvar in empdepartment)
{
    string Designame = empvar.Designation[0].DesignationName.ToString(); 
}
```